# Extracting data in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a col Test_Name in which I have a total of 15000 records. In this col there are in total 14 distinct variables which have different counts. For eg Test name A has 347 counts B has 1500 C has 233 count D has 40 and E has 12 counts etc resp.
Now i want that where ever the count is >100 I  should get random 100 records for a specific test or if I get the first 100 records for each test which has a count >100 would be just fine in either case.

how can i do that in SAS?  An early response would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. Can you post some more details? It sounds like a proc surveyselect. Also, what happens if you have < 100.

Answer (score 0):

Here is away you can just get the data from 100th record in the keep dataset

```
proc sort data=test;
by test_Name;
run;

data new keep;
    set test;
    by Test_Name;
    if first.Test_Name then n=0;
    n+1;
    if n=99 then output keep;
run;
```